# How to make polynomial features using sparse matrix in Scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, data-science, polynomials, sklearn-pandas

I am using Scikit-learn for converting my train data to polynomials features and then fit it to a linear model.

```
model = Pipeline([('poly', PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)),
              ('linear', LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False))])
model.fit(X, y)
```

But it throws an error

```
TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required
```

I know my data is `sparse matrix` format. So when I try to convert my data to `dense matrix` it shows `memory error`. Because my data is huge(50k~). Because of these large amounts of data I can't convert it to a dense matrix.

I also find [Github Issues](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8376) where this feature is requested. But still not implemented.

So please can someone tell how to use sparse data format in PolynomialFeatures in Scikit-learn without converting it to dense format?

Comment: As you have already discussed this on the github issue, there's little we can do here at stackoverflow. Maybe you can try implementing your own version and come here when finding difficulties in that.

Comment: Seems like the developers have make a PR for [the same here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/10452). Please have a look at it.

Comment: Fair points. Try selecting a subset of your columns only in order to create polynomial features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new feature in the upcoming 0.20 version of sklearn. See [Release History - V0.20 - Enhancements](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/whats_new.html#enhancements) If you really wanted to test it out you could install the development version by following the instructions in [Sklean - Advanced Installation - Install Bleeding Edge](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/developers/advanced_installation.html#install-bleeding-edge).

Comment: Can you please also say when will 0.20 will move to the stable version?

Answer (score 2):

Since [version 0.21.0](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/whats_new.html#id36), the [PolynomialFeatures](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html#sklearn-preprocessing-polynomialfeatures) class accepts CSR matrices for degrees 2 and 3. The method laid out [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.06418) is used, and the computation is much, much faster than if the input is a CSC matrix or dense (assuming the data's sparse to any reasonable degree - even slightly).

Answer (score 1):

While we are waiting for the latest update of Sklearn - you can find an implementation of sparse interaction here:

https://github.com/drivendataorg/box-plots-sklearn/blob/master/src/features/SparseInteractions.py